# PHP Imagick not working with pdf generated by Microsoft EDGE

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

So I am working on a project which is in PHP. I need to convert pdf pages into images.

For this, I am using Imagick library.

Here is my code

```
        $imagick = new imagick($pdfPath);
        $noOfPagesInPDF = $imagick->getNumberImages();
        $pdfAbsolutePath = $pdfPath;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $noOfPagesInPDF; $i++) {
            $url = $pdfAbsolutePath . '[' . $i . ']';
            $img = new imagick();
            $img->setResolution(150, 150);
            $im->setImageBackgroundColor('black');
            $img->readImage($url); 
            $img->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
            $img->setImageFormat('jpeg');
            $img->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
            $img->setImageCompressionQuality(70);

            $base64EncodeData = base64_encode($img->getImageBlob());
            $imageSrc = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'. $base64EncodeData;
            $img->clear();
            $img->destroy();
            renderImage($imageSrc);
        }
```

In my renderImage function, I am just appending an image tag in the  Html.

This is working fine for all the pdf except those who created by Microsoft PDF creator.

For those pdf, it's giving blank images.

I tried to run convert the pdf from the command line and getting the following error. 
[image]

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: Add the issue occurs only for certain pdfs, you might want to share an example pdf to allow reproductive the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay if anybody else having the same issue, updating Ghostscript version did the trick for me.

Download [GhostScript-9.25 zip](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) and run following commands.

```
tar xvf ghostscript-9.25.tar.gz
sudo apt-get install build-essential
cd ghostscript-9.25/
sudo ./configure
sudo make install (it may take 2 to 3 min)
```